# Geotools - get beside parces

Tags: geotools

I have a problem needed help. I have parces map layer in postgis which contain polygons. This layer is following by not overlap topology rule.
How could i get features that "beside" a selected feature with geotools api? The "beside" feature is feature have at least one same edge.[image]

For example in this picture, when select feature A, i need to get feature B,C,D, not get feature E.

Any help is high appreciate! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by this code

public static void getRoundFeature(SimpleFeature feature, SimpleFeatureSource featureSource){
    FilterFactory2 ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();
    GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory( null );
    Geometry g = (Geometry) feature.getAttribute("the_geom");

```
Polygon polygon = geometryFactory.createPolygon(g.getCoordinates());
//Polygon poly = (Polygon) feature;
Filter filter = ff.intersects(ff.property("the_geom"), ff.literal(polygon));
try {
    SimpleFeatureCollection featureCollection = featureSource.getFeatures(filter);
    //System.out.println("feature around: "+ featureCollection.size());
    FeatureIterator iter = featureCollection.features();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        SimpleFeature rfeature = (SimpleFeature) iter.next();
        System.out.println("so to: "+rfeature.getAttribute("soto")+ "so thua: "+rfeature.getAttribute("sothua"));
    }

} catch (IOException e) { LOGGER.log(Level.FINER, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

}